# Which dependency I should add to get txt file in s3 with scala-spark using intelliJ?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I'm using IntelliJ ide and language scala, I want to access a text file stored in AWS S3, using IAM user credentials. I have not downloaded Hadoop on my system just using the dependencies. I have done this using the Aws dependencies and jets3t dependencies. But I want to do it with spark.

Basic errors I'm getting is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found,
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem not found 
// and similarly
Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem not found.
```

Please help me how should I solve this problem.

I have tried adding various Hadoop dependencies, hadoop-aws dependencies independently and each gave me a different error.
Like adding "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "3.2.0" says:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StreamCapabilities
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

adding "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "3.1.1" says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:699)
                    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:828)
                    at spark_scala_s3$.main(spark_scala_s3.scala:40).
                for the line:
                val df = sc.textFile(s"s3a://my-week6-spark/$path").
```

adding "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.7.3" says:

```
  com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, 
 AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 90C42E72BEEB31FB, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request, S3 Extended Request ID: (someid).
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: AKIAUAOZGFGM2K5WEHFC:l0IHiYq4ApJEewbjKR00KwKA+Ra)
  and 
  The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
```

Code:

```
// Dependencies in sbt:
    version := "0.1"
    scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.3"
     // and others I added to see what works but gave errors as above
```

Actual scala file code

```
// just 1 import
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val s = SparkSession.builder().appName("trial2").master("local").getOrCreate()
val sc = s.sparkContext

var accessKeyId: String = "acc key"
val secretAccessKey: String = "secret acc key"
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", accessKeyId)                     
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", accessKeyId)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", accessKeyId)   
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey",
secretAccessKey)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", 
secretAccessKey)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key",secretAccessKey)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.impl", 
"org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")                          
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl", 
"org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.impl", 
"org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem")
try{
    val df = sc.textFile(s"s3a://my-week6-spark/$path")
    // my-week6-spark is bucket name
    // path consist of file name
    println("DF.show() 1\n",df.collect())            
catch {
      case exception: Exception => println("1 failed as 
",exception)
     }
try{
   val df = sc.textFile(s"s3n://my-week6-spark/$path")
   println("DF.show() 2\n",df.collect())
}catch {
   case exception: Exception => println("2 failed as ", exception)
       }
try{
   val df = sc.textFile(s"s3://my-week6-spark/$path")
   println("DF.show() 3\n",df.collect())
}catch {
   case exception: Exception => println("3 failed as ", exception)
}
}
```

I expected the contents of the file would be accessed and print some content as per it. But I'm getting the errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StreamCapabilities
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

and as mentioned above with each dependency it shows a different error.

I got one solution online where it says to sets the Hadoop path:
as:
Export hadoop_path = some path.

but as I have not installed Hadoop I can 't provide any path where it is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by adding the below dependencies from Maven:

Use the same version of hadoop-aws, hadoop-common and hadoop-map-reduce dependencies.

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "3.1.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "3.1.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core" % "3.1.2"

dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.7"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.7"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.12" % "2.8.7"
```

As the inbuilt jackson jars were not supported I had to override them for new version instead of just adding them.

Comment: This suggestion is working